# percent does not work on area() function - formattable

Tags: r, formattable

I try to create a table with percent value using `area()` function. But actually it does not work at all (i.e. percent value). Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
#library(magrittr)
#library(dplyr)
#library(formattable)
#library(scales)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10, 
             a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10), c = rnorm(10))

df <- df %>% 
    mutate(a = percent(a), b = percent(b), c = percent(c))

# show percentage value without using area function
formattable(df, list(a = color_tile("transparent", "pink"),
                     b = color_tile("transparent", "pink"),
                     c = color_tile("transparent", "pink")))

# does not show percentage value
formattable(df, list(area(col = a:c) ~ color_tile("transparent", "pink")))

sessionInfo()

[1] formattable_0.2   DT_0.1            scales_0.4.0 
[4] tidyr_0.4.1       rCharts_0.4.5     dplyr_0.4.3      
[7] shiny_0.13.2
```

Comment: You are using a few packages in  your reproducible code. Could you specify which? E.g. magrittr, dplyr,  scales, formattable..?

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best results I've gotten have been using this code:

```
formattable(df, list(area(col = a:c) ~ percent))
```

But I don't know how to change the number of digits in the number :(

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the Liliana's comment:

You can also specify the number of decimals when you create your own function first, ie:

```
percent2 <- function(x) {
   x <- percent(x, 2)
}
```

Then you can use this with a tilde with a predefined number of decimals.

```
formattable(df, list(area(col = a:c) ~ percent2))
```